# SVN repo browser does not show an open TCP connection on backend

Tags: linux, tcp, svn

When I am connected to mysvnserver using the repo browser (TortoiseSVN), I do not see an open connection when I perform a netstat on the mysvnserver box and grep for my computer.  What is the behavior?  Does it download an index file and cache it locally so that I don't need a persistent connection to the svn server?  Why then do I see many other computers connected to that server using the svn protocol?  What operation would cause a stateful connection?  Is it only check in/commit and check out?

Answer (score 4):

SVN is typically not a stateful connection. Think of your subversion server the same as a web server (which in many cases, it is). Web servers do not keep stateful connections, and neither will SVN.